# add is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, trie

I have no idea why I'm getting this error, I'm using trie.js from github and trying to use the add function, but it says that trie.add isn't a function.

```js
var longestWord = function(words) {
    console.log('test');
    let trie = new Trie();
    trie.add("test");
    console.log(trie);
};


longestWord('testing');

function Trie() {
    this.head = {
            key : ''
        , children: {}
    }
}

Trie.prototype.add = function(key) {

    var curNode = this.head
        , newNode = null
        , curChar = key.slice(0,1);

    key = key.slice(1);
    
    while(typeof curNode.children[curChar] !== "undefined" 
        && curChar.length > 0){
        curNode = curNode.children[curChar];
        curChar = key.slice(0,1);
        key = key.slice(1);
    }

    while(curChar.length > 0) {
        newNode = {
                key : curChar
            , value : key.length === 0 ? null : undefined
            , children : {}
        };

        curNode.children[curChar] = newNode;

        curNode = newNode;

        curChar = key.slice(0,1);
        key = key.slice(1);
    }

};

Trie.prototype.search = function(key) {
    var curNode = this.head
        , curChar = key.slice(0,1)
        , d = 0;

    key = key.slice(1);

    while(typeof curNode.children[curChar] !== "undefined" && curChar.length > 0){
        curNode = curNode.children[curChar];
        curChar = key.slice(0,1);
        key = key.slice(1);
        d += 1;
    }

    if (curNode.value === null && key.length === 0) {
        return d;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

}

Trie.prototype.remove = function(key) {
    var d = this.search(key);
    if (d > -1){
        removeH(this.head, key, d);
    }
}

function removeH(node, key, depth) {
    if (depth === 0 && Object.keys(node.children).length === 0){
        return true;
    } 

    var curChar = key.slice(0,1);

    if (removeH(node.children[curChar], key.slice(1), depth-1)) {
        delete node.children[curChar];
        if (Object.keys(node.children).length === 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

All the code I added myself is before function Trie(). The rest of it is from this github repo: https://gist.github.com/alexandervasyuk/b12c3d2c306539decb2a#file-trie-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling new Trie before adding prototypes to it.

This is working version:

https://jsbin.com/jokekuw/3/edit?js,output

```js
var longestWord = function(words) {
    console.log('test');
    let trie = new Trie();
    trie.add("test");
};

function Trie() {
    this.head = {
            key : ''
        , children: {}
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create complete executable examples right here in the Stack Overflow site, just like the OP did. There's really no need to use an external playground site.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be moved to *after* the Trie declaration and prototype initialization.

The Trie constructor function (`Trie`) declaration will be hoisted to the top of the code block. Your code can therefore be successful in instantiating a new object with it. However, at the time you try to *use* the object, the Trie prototype has not yet been initialized. The prototype initialization statements are just ordinary statements, so they will be executed *after* your call to `longestWord()`.

Thus if you move everything of yours that is currently before `function Trie ...` to the end of the overall code block, it should work (barring other errors).

Comment: Also that code you found is not really a GitHub "repo"; it's just a code gist. It's 5 years old and there's no way of knowing if anybody has ever successfully used it.